# getting decimals when diving doubles

Tags: java, formatting, double

I wrote this method to find the avarage lenght of tokens in a string. I'm having a hard time getting the decimas from this division (two doubles).

```
public static double averageTokenLength (Scanner s)
{
    String word="";
    int words = 0;
    int length = 0;
    double average = 0;

while (s.hasNext())
{
    word = s.next();
    words++;
    length = length + word.length();    
    average = (length/ words);

}

return average;
```

The test method I was given by the professor shows "expected; 3.66666666666667, but was 3.0. How can i get my code to show that result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
length * 1.0 / words
```

Otherwise it does the division between integers, for example 7/3 gives you 2 with remainder of 1.

Comment: it did the trick, so basically it is just to make sure that we divide 34.0/ words rather than 34/words? sorry I tried to tag you in the comment but I couldnt figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the other answers would be to do an explicit cast of one of the arguments, like this:

```
(double)length/words;
```

It's a few characters extra, but it's more explicit about what you're doing, which might be useful if you or someone else are looking at the code later.

Answer (score 0):

you should use `length*1.0/words` instead